# Overwriting Internet Ads with our own for our Proxy Server

Tags: proxy, bind

We offer free internet access to customers. We proxy all we can to improve speed as it is a heavily used service.

If not illegal, we would like to offer our own google and non google ads in places on sites where they'd generally be.

First, is this illegal? Second, does Google ads allow this?

Comment: First, this would be something for a lawyer.  Second, Google should be the one to answer that.

Comment: I'll get legal advice for the legalities. Is this something that is done often on free internet connections?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is prohibited in Google's terms of service.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on evil.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever this sort of shady scheme is brought up, it is met with almost universal dislike from all camps.

### Technologically

More and more websites are moving to full-time HTTPS, meaning it simply wouldn't work... OR you would have to develop even MORE slimy and intrusive man-in-the-middle attacks faking SSL certs to accomplish what you want to do.

### Web Users

When a surfer requests a page from a site, she expects to get the page that the site served. This is to say nothing of unknowingly breaking functionality by attempting to replace http code in sites.

### Web site owners

Now, I am not a lawyer, but if I own a site and make money from every page impression through advertising, I would sure as hell sue you for stolen revenue if you removed the revenue-generating portions of my page and then served my content. It's just as bad as stealing content and putting it on your own separate site. Worse even... you're still using my bandwidth!

Comment: Thanks for the response, it is really helpful and brings things into perspective. I'll have a talk with my dear leader, and hopefully this will be the end of it.